# Angular directive to preselect <select> value if only one option exists in ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to write directive that will check for available options in the scope and preselect some option if only one item present inside ngOptions.

For now I wrote something like this:

```
<select id="provider" name="provider" class="form-control"
        ng-model="foo.provider"
        ng-options="provider.name for provider in providers track by provider.id"
        select-first-if-only-one="providers"
        required>
    <option value="">- Select -</option>
</select>
```

and my directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app')
    .directive('selectFirstIfOnlyOne', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'select',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                scope.$watchCollection(attrs.selectFirstIfOnlyOne, function(values) {
                    if (angular.isDefined(values) && values.length === 1) {
                        scope.$evalAsync(function() {
                            ctrl.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(values[0]);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

And it works. But I want not to pass array values to directive directly but to take them from ngModel or ngOptions.

I found that [`SelectController`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/aff74ec87bd31933565b76cd0ab0b988cd9bae21/src/ng/directive/select.js#L22) doesn't provide methods to get all values from `<select>`, same for [`NgModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

Comment: You can create a custom element directive that create the select element and bind the options to it

Comment: require ngModel in your directive and go from there?

Comment: @pQuestions123 `ngModel` will bind the value of the select and not its options

Comment: @Alon I am saying to just require both in the custom directive. Pull array from ngmodel and then do your thing...

Comment: How can I read values from ngModel?

Comment: @rand0m86 Read the bottom part of this tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: @rand0m86 https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController. Looks like you already have reference to ngModelCtrl. just use ngModelCtrl.$modelValue.

Comment: @pQuestions123 I get undefined via ctrl.ngModelCtrl.$modelValue

Answer (score 3):

Something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jafgo1ru/) will work if you don't plan on changing the ng-options without reloading the scope.

First off, you can't get information (as far as I'm aware) from ng-options. NgModel has no value yet, that's what you are trying to set with this directive if there is only one option.

You can do it this way sharing the scope with the controller:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="cont">
    <select id="provider" name="provider" class="form-control"
        ng-model="foo.provider"
        ng-options="provider.name for provider in providers track by provider.id"
        select-first-if-only-one="providers"
            required>
        <option value="">- Select -</option>
    </select>
</div>

angular.module('app', [])
.controller('cont', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = {}
    $scope.providers = [{name: 'bob', id: 1}]
})
.directive('selectFirstIfOnlyOne', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (scope.providers.length < 2) {
                scope.foo.provider = scope.providers[0];
            }
        }
    };
});
```

If you want to isolate the scope you'll need to pass the information through an isolated scope var:

html
    select-first-if-only-one="providers.length"

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('cont', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = {}
    $scope.providers = [{name: 'bob', id: 1}]
})
.directive('selectFirstIfOnlyOne', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {options: '=selectFirstIfOnlyOne', model: '=ngModel'},
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (scope.options.length < 2) {
                scope.model = scope.options[0];
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Sorry, I was doing this a bit rushed and can change this even further if your still not satisfied.

Comment: This way directive will be highly coupled to controller and I'm trying to avoid this

Comment: add a scope to the directive and pass in the variable, I'll edit the post.

Comment: I understand what you're talking about now, and I don't think you can get any information form ng-options into your directive and you wont be able to get any information from ng-model because it isn't selected yet. I'll still re-write my answer with an isolated scope, but you will still need to pass some information rather than collecting it from ng-options.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with regex:

http://jsfiddle.net/PxdSP/3206/

Code:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('selectFirstIfOnlyOne', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'select',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        var regex = /in (.+?)(?: |$)/; //Here
        var collection = regex.exec(attrs.ngOptions)[1]; // And here

        scope.$watchCollection(collection, function (values) {
          if (angular.isDefined(values) && values.length === 1) {
            scope.$evalAsync(function () {
              ctrl.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(values[0]);
              ctrl.ngModelCtrl.$render();
            });
          }
        });
      }
    };
});
```